# Convert icon file to XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, icons

I have several windows icons that I would like to use in an existing WPF application.

The application uses XAML DrawingImages that are in a ResourceDictionary.

Is there a way to convert my windows icon files to a XAML DrawingImage?

Answer (score 1):

You could directly create a `BitmapImage` from an icon file, like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon1" UriSource="Icons/Icon1.ico" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and e.g. use that as the `Source` of an Image control

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource Icon1}" />
```

or as well for a DrawingImage, like

```
<DrawingImage>
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <ImageDrawing ImageSource="{StaticResource Icon1}"/>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

Comment: I have created a folder called Icons in my dll project and copied in my icon file (icon1.ico) but it gives the error "Could not find a part of the path C:\Windows\System32\Icons\icon1.ico"

Comment: My only difference is that I am using in inside <Grid.Resources> and not <Window.Resources>

Comment: And for some reason you get an absolute path. Where does it come from? If there is an Icon file in your VS project, its Build Action should be set to Resource.

Comment: OK I have checked and your method works when I use it in the MainWindow XAML file! However I am using it in a custom Control with its own XAML ControlTemplate.  WHy would this be any different?

Comment: You might have to use a full [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx), including the assembly name, like `pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/Icons/Icon1.ico`.